# MongoDB regex, and operators - how to find by two values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this following query:

```
Batch.find({batchNumber: {$regex : "^" + "20pp"}}, null, { sort: { batchNumber: -1 } }, function (err, orders) {
if(err) throw err;
res.json(orders);
});
```

With that query I get all the Batches which start with `"20pp"`.

I would like to get all the Batches which start with `"20pp"` AND `"21pp"` but I could not find any solution for it.
Is it possible ?
Is there any way to use $and ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concat search strings using `|` operator,

```
Batch.find({ batchNumber: { $regex : "^20pp|^21pp" } }, null, { sort: { batchNumber: -1 } }, function (err, orders) {
  if(err) throw err;
  res.json(orders);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do following way as well:

```
db.Batch.find({batchNumber:/^2[0,1]pp/},{batchNumber:1,_id:0}).sort({batchNumber:-1})
```